# Are Sharepoint Calendars Separate from Exchange Calendars?

Tags: calendar

We're going to be implementing Sharepoint 2013 and we have a need to include calendars on the sites. Our current line of thinking is that we'll need to create exchange mailboxes and calendars for each site.  I'm trying to find out if Sharepoint 2013 has it's own separate calendaring options and what it's benefits and limitations are when compared to integrated exchange calendars.

In my search all I could find were how-to's for users to use calendars and exchange integration steps.  If anyone knows of a good technet article or can share personal experience which addresses this I'd greatly appreciate it.  My exact questions are this:

*Does Sharepoint 2013 have its own calendaring system or does it rely on Exchange for calendars?  If Sharepoint has its own, how does it compare to an Exchange 2010 calendar?*

Comment: @Raystafarian Actually, I asked this question here before I was pointed to the sharepoint SE (I didn't know it existed).  I flagged my question for migration there instead.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint calendars are just lists dressed up and are completely separate from Exchange. You can create a new Calendar list in SP 2013 and on top in the Ribbon choose 'Connect to Outlook'. Grant permissions and you have a two way sync between SP and Exchange calendar.

https://kx.cloudingenium.com/microsoft/servers/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/how-to-synchronize-content-between-sharepoint-2013-and-outlook/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

SharePoint 2013 has calendar functionality that is independent of exchange.

As you noted, you can integrate with Outlook and have visibility over your personal outlook calendar and a site calendar.

Each site can be set-up to have their own calendar(s).

Comment: Can you link me to documentation which either describes a comparison of the two?  Or, to documentation which describes Sharepoint calendar features (I can compare that to what I already know about Exchange calendars)?

Comment: @Colyn1337 The below link is not really a comparison, but more of a end-user walk through on how to do things.  In my experience, OOB SharePoint calendars are basically WYSIWYG.  For example, adding color coded events (categories) which is part of Outlook requires a little configuration on SP calendars.      

[link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/sharepoint-calendars-i-make-the-most-of-your-team-calendar-RZ010255072.aspx)